# Delphi SQL Update single record using string variable

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have the following coding. Every time someone wants to buy a cd the quantity must be deducted. When I use the cd name the coding work, but when I use a string veriable nothing happens. Please help.

```
var scd : string;
begin
   scd := inputbox('CD Name','Enter CD Name','');
   CDQuery.Active := False;
   cdquery.SQL.Clear;
   CDQuery.SQL.Text := 'Update CD_Table Set Quantity = Quantity - 1 where Cdname = ''scd''';
   CDQuery.ExecSQL;
   messageDlg('Quantity was updated',mtInformation,[mbOK],0);
   CDQuery.SQL.text := 'Select * from CD_Table';
   CDQuery.Active := True;
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you search for a CD named scd and not the value that you entered in you input box. You need to pass that value to the query as a parameter

something like this should do the trick :

```
var
  scd: string;
begin
  scd := inputbox('CD Name', 'Enter CD Name', '');
  CDQuery.Active := False;
  CDQuery.SQL.Clear;
  CDQuery.SQL.Text := 'Update CD_Table Set Quantity = Quantity - 1 where Cdname = :Cdname';
  CDQuery.ParamByName('Cdname').AsString := scd;
  CDQuery.ExecSQL;
  MessageDlg('Quantity was updated', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
  CDQuery.SQL.Text := 'Select * from CD_Table';
  CDQuery.Active := True;
end;
```